# Opencv matrix per-element operation

Tags: c++, opencv, matrix

I have a `cv::Mat` and I want to do some per-element operation. For example, I have a float matrix like `cv::Mat m(100,100, CV_64F);`. I have another function like below:

```
double fun(double elem);
```

How to apply this function to a matrix, which can do per-element operation.

Answer (score 5):

You can do it like this:

```
double func(double x)
{
    return(sin(x));
}

int main(void)
{
    Mat M=Mat::eye(3,3,CV_64FC1);
    std::transform(M.begin<double>(),M.end<double>(),M.begin<double>(),func);
    cout << M;
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: very elegant solution using standard library. However I wonder if it's really efficient as far as performance is concerned, because from old experiments MatIterator is much slower than accessing row data directly

Comment: @remi but maybe MatIterator performance is depended of the type of the libraries you are using (debug/release), as in the case of the Mat::at() method? I mean, in realease version performance is quite high.

Comment: @marol I was talking comparative performances, using the same environment (release version of opencv), btw raw data and MatIterator. raw data > Mat.at > MatIterator if I remember well, but not sure what's the best btw mat.at and iterator. This seems quite normal because mat.at always computes the shift from the beginning of the matrix, and takes care of the fact that mat.isContinuous() is not required, and so does MatIterator. If you know your matrix is continuous, and want the best processing time, just use raw data pointers

Comment: Your task is matrix scan, you can find good explanation with perfomance analysis here: http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/core/how_to_scan_images/how_to_scan_images.html   (may be lookup table also will be useful).

Answer (score 2):

1)Check that your mat is continuous

```
if(mat.isContinuous())
```

2)Access row data pointer and cast it to double

```
double* buffer = (double*)mat.data; 
// or
double* buffer = mat.ptr<double>(0);
double *bufferEnd = (double*)mat.end;
```

3)Call your function on each elem of the buffer, e.g.

```
 for (; buffer != bufferEnd; ++buffer)
        *buffer = fun(*buffer)
```

Answer (score 1):

What about simply loop?

```
cv::Mat m(100, 100, CV_64F);
for(int x=0;x<m.cols;x++)
    for(int y=0;y<m.rows;y++)
        m.at<double>(y,x) = fun(m.at<double>(y,x));
```

This is pretty fast if you use release version of opencv libraries. If you can change source of fun function that it changes the argument itself instead of returning it form function:

```
void fun(double &elem);
```

You can then omit one at() call:

```
cv::Mat m(100, 100, CV_64F);
for(int x=0;x<m.cols;x++)
    for(int y=0;y<m.rows;y++)
        fun(m.at<double>(y,x));
```

Answer (score 0):

Design a generic for loop for the matrix

```
/**
 *@brief apply stl like for_each algorithm on every channels
 *
 * @param T : the type of the channel(ex, uchar, float, double and so on)
 * @param func : Unary function that accepts an element in the range as argument
 *
 *@return :
 *  return func
 */
template<typename T, typename UnaryFunc, typename Mat>
UnaryFunc for_each_channels(Mat &&input, UnaryFunc func)
{
    int rows = input.rows;
    int cols = input.cols;

    if(input.isContinuous()){
        cols = input.total() * input.channels();
        rows = 1;
    }

    for(int row = 0; row != rows; ++row){
        auto begin = input.template ptr<T>(row);
        auto end = begin + cols;
        while(begin != end){
            func(*begin);
            ++begin;
        }
    }

    return func;
}
```

Use it as following

```
cv::Mat m(100, 100, CV_64F);
//......initialize m
for_each_channels<double>(m, [](double &a)
{
    a = std::sin(a) * 2.14168;;
});
```

You could extend the api to support vector type too

```
for_each<cv::vec3d>(m, [](cv::vec3d& a)
{
    a = ..... //do something
});
```

I already design some generic api to use, I put them at [github](https://github.com/stereomatchingkiss/ocv_libs/blob/master/core/for_each.hpp)